# angular cli installation fails at step fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule chokidar@1.7.0 checking installable status

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

I am new to angular cli. 
Trying to install angular cli on windows machine in my company(behind proxy). Have installed node and npm. 
Using npm I also installed typescript packages. 
However the angular cli installation fails at below step:

```
[   ...............] / fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule chokidar@1.7.0 checking installable status
```

I am running below command :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Below is the log being shown on the command prompt:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-WIr7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd3b2KxIXC5Q== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-WIr
7iDkdmdbxu/Gh6eKEZJL6KPE74/5MEsf2whTOFNxbIoIixogroLdKYqB6FDav4Wavh/lZdzzd3b2KxIXC5Q== but got sha512-2DqIGeAfFMb8eI+LZWl53bx0sCPMI5M8SVVIXjRomxiUY1Jcy2NK79gnR2gRam3TDi
lxUjaUlRoCBVIC9KpVNg==. (1597 bytes)
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry
npm WARN tar invalid entry

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<UserID>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-06T05_21_15_837Z-debug.log
```

**Note: I have also set the proxy to npm config and have set strict-ssl=false**

Comment: Its not an issue specific to angular cli. I got the same when I was trying to install node-sass. Make sure proper proxy settings

Answer (score 4):

I managed to resolve this issue by following these steps.

> 1. rm -rf node_modules/
> 2. npm cache clean --force
> 3. npm cache verify
> 4. npm i -g @angular/cli

Also make sure you set the proxies properly.

Comment: this does the work. But can you explain why it is needed to clear the cache, as this is the first time i am installing cli in my machine, no other npm packages were installed

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I was getting while installing the `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` package. I have resolved by upgrading `node` and `npm` versions to latest. 
After that please follow the below steps to install the `angular/cli`:

1) Open your command prompt with administrative privileges and uninstall `angular/cli` by using `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` command.

2) You can try deleting `node_modules` from your project directory and then clear the cache by using `npm cache clear --force` command.

3) Remove `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` directory.

4) Try to install the `angular/cli@latest` by using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` command.

Hope the above trick resolve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've faced this problem and I tried all the answers on Stackoverflow, finally I found solution for this issue:
first you have to uninstall nodejs and remove all the files related him
then go to "Register Editor" and search for all "nodejs", "node.js" and delete them
Restart your computer
and reinstall nodejs then install angular.
it's worked for me